# Is node.js runnning on it's own web server or does it use apache/nginx?

Tags: node.js

I'm interested in choosing a best web server for node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is used to create, among other things, servers.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs):

> Node.js is a software system designed for writing scalable internet applications, notably web servers.

So, you don't need to get another web server. You do need to get a machine that lets you install node. A lot of people prefer [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) which lets you run machines, and install whatever you want. Another popular option is [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) which tries to take complexeties out of it. I, honestly, get more confused by it. Pretty sure you could also go with something like [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/index.php?cm_mmc=PPCHybridBU-_-Google-_-exact-_-rackspace&OVMTC=Exact&site=&creative=2911163056&OVKEY=rackspace&url_id=18219500&adpos=1t1&ic_pl_id=18219500&ic_lp_id=6171624&cdid=4677).

Comment: It is recommend to put something battle tested in front of it though, i guess for buffering performance and potential security issues, such as haproxy (heroku choice I believe) or nginx (dotclouds choice).

Answer (score 0):

node.js isn't "running" on neither its own nor apache/nginx, it doesn't need a webserver to run at all (imagine a node.js script that copies files for example). it depends on what you intend to use it for. however if you want you can write a webserver in node.js very easily, it has good HTTP support: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html

And sure you can (if you have written a webserver in node.js) put it behind apache/nginx to let them serve static files for example or to use https (since SSL support for node.js isn't very stable yet compared to apache/nginx)